Obfuscating data in BigQuery
I want to automate the obfuscation of some data in BigQuery. For example replacing all instances of joe.bloggs@gmail.com in a table with abc@replaced, where joe.bloggs@gmail.com could be in any column (even as a substring of the column).
My current approach is to find matches by turning the entire row into a JSON string:
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
WHERE CONTAINS_SUBSTR(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(a), " ", ""), "joe.bloggs@gmail.com")) 

and then deleting the entire row with:
DELETE FROM `project.dataset.table` a
WHERE CONTAINS_SUBSTR(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(a), " ", "")), "joe.bloggs@gmail.com")

I'm having a hard time figuring out an approach that updates instead of deleting.
For some extra context these queries run as part of a Python script that scans hundreds of datasets and tables, so it must be mindful of cost.

I'm assuming that the sensistive data you want masked/replaced exists within a String column as opposed to it being a column of its own?  If it were a column of its own, you could apply a Policy Tag to redact/replace the returned results while the original content remained.  It feels like you could automate what you want using the Sensitive Data Protection (SDP) capabilities .... see  https://cloud.google.com/sensitive-data-protection/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data

BigQuery has some features that maybe help, such as Dynamic Data Masking and Sensitive Data Protection scan.

Thanks both, it looks like Sensitive Data Protection is probably what I'm looking for, because I don't want to obfuscate all email addresses, I just want to be able to de-identify customers who've asked to be forgotten.

Having said that, documentation isn't particularly clear on how to actually use this to replace a specific token.

If you want to remove/redact/mask specific sensistive strings ... eg bob@example.com then likely neither masking nor SDP will be of use.  Both assume that you want to redact all or nothing ... not "some".   Depending on the need, I'm almost tempted to suggest creating a table of "identities" with a unique key.  Then use SDP to find all identies in the text and replace with a reference to the key.  Then when you want to remove a user, you remove the table row that contains identity and they are gone everywhere.

Thanks @Kolban, that would be a good solution if I could re-architect from the start, but it's a bit more challenging for a project reading from dozens of data sources in a variety of projects. In the end I'm going to use the Policy Tags that we already have to limit where we scan. This approach risks missing any data if anyone has forgotten to tag a column, but I've checked that all cols with *email*, *tel* and *phone* in the name are tagged.

I'm absolutely no legal expert ... however ... by using Policy Tags, you are restricting who can see data in the table.  This means that if user bob@example.com needs to be "forgotten" ... that won't actually have happened.  By using Policy Tags, you have restricted who can see the users ... BUT ... with the correct permissions, the users can still be seen/found.  They have not been deleted ... is this sufficient for the business case?

@kolban you're right, what I'm meaning is that I scan through table metadata to find columns with Policy Tags applied, then run an UPDATE query to update those columns, as opposed to scanning all cols in all tables. So the data does get removed, Policy Tags are just used as a guide to identify which columns should be scanned.

As an idea.
You can search and find columns in table, without listing column names.
You have table name and get column name with search value.
Then,with table name and column names, create dynamic query for update(replace ...) columns in table.
UPDATE <table name>
SET <column name>=replace(<column name>,<search value>,<substitute value>)
WHERE instr(<column name>,<search value>)>0

See example:
Source table



id
code
description
contacts




1
code1
this is description 1
Client email is abc@mail.com,address:Client1 adr


2
code2
this is description for client2 with abc@mail.com for test
Client email is abc2@mail.com, address:Client3 adr


3
code3
this is description for client3 with other@mail.com for test
Client email is abc3@mail.com, address:Client3 adr



CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonObjectKeys(input STRING)
RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonObjectValues(input STRING)
RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";

WITH src as(
  select 1 id,'code1' code,'this is description 1' description,'Client email is abc@mail.com, address:Client1 adr' contacts
  union all
  select 2 id,'code2' ,'this is description for client2 with abc@mail.com for test','Client email is abc2@mail.com, address:Client1 adr'
  union all
  select 3 id,'code2' ,'this is description for client2 with other@mail.com for test','Client email is abc2@mail.com, address:Client1 adr'
  )
, data AS (
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(a) AS jdata FROM src a
)
,keys AS (
  SELECT jdata,
    jsonObjectKeys(jdata) AS keys
   ,jsonObjectValues(jdata) AS vals
  from data
)
SELECT
   i,columnName,columnValue
   ,case when instr(columnValue,'abc@mail.com')>0 then 1 else 0 end isFound
FROM keys
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(keys.keys)  AS columnName with offset i
left join unnest(keys.vals)AS columnValue with offset j
   on i=j
where instr(jdata,'abc@mail.com')>0
ORDER BY i

Output is



row
i
columnName
columnValue
isFound




1
0
id
1
0


2
0
id
2
0


3
1
code
code1
0


4
1
code
code2
0


5
2
description
this is description 1
0


6
2
description
this is description for client2 with abc@mail.com for test
1


7
3
contacts
Client email is abc@mail.com, address:Client1 adr
1


8
3
contacts
Client email is abc2@mail.com, address:Client1 adr
0



See here for json keys
Example in BigQuery

It's a good idea thanks. Very expensive due to the whole table scans but looks like a safe option.
